# NSMutableAttributedString UILabel is not retaining its attributes when selected

Tags: uitableview, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring

I am having issues with retaining an attributed NSMutableString. I have a UITableView who's each UITableViewCell has an attributed text. Setting the attributed text is no problem, but upon selection, the UITableViewCell's attributes is lost. This is my code in **cellForRowAtIndexPath** that sets the attribute:

```
  NSMutableAttributedString *changesStyleString_h = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Attributes change!" attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20], NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor yellowColor]}];

[changesStyleString_h addAttributes:@{ NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName:@(1)} range:NSMakeRange(11, 6)];
cell.mainLabel.attributedText = changesStyleString
```

might i point out that **mainLabel** is also a UILabel, no customization there. Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I found that I needed to set attributes on the ENTIRE string, or it would do funky things.

```
NSString* string = @"1 - some string"
NSMutableAttributedString* string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string];
[string setAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: accent, NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:13.f]} range:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
```

This would cause weird behavior when highlighting the cell.

However, when I did this:

```
[string setAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blackColor]} range:NSMakeRange(1, [labelTwo length] - 1)];
```

Everything seemed to work as expected.

Hope that helps!